# React form not rendering with selectedRow data

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am new to React.js so forgive me if this is an obvious mistake.  I have a list of data with an update button on each row and it is supposed to open a form with the relevant fields already populated with the `selectedRow.data` but the controls are blank.  The URL in Postman is giving the right response so that's not the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Also getting this error in my console:

```
"Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component"
```

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';
import AdminPortal from '../apis/AdminPortal'


const OrganizationUpdateForm = (props) => {
  const {id} = useParams()
  const { organizations } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [shortName, setShortName] = useState("");
  const [parentOrg, setParentOrg] = useState("");
  const [website, setWebsite] = useState("");
  const [comments, setComments] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData () {
      const response = await AdminPortal.get(`organizations/${id}`);
      console.log(response.data.data);
      setName(response.data.data.organizations.name);
      setShortName(response.data.data.organizations.short_name);
      setParentOrg(response.data.data.organizations.parent_org);
      setWebsite(response.data.data.organizations.website);
      setComments(response.data.data.organizations.comments);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  

  let Navigate  = useNavigate(); 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updateOrganization = await AdminPortal.put(`organizations/${id}`, {
      name,
      short_name: shortName,
      parent_org: parentOrg,
      website,
      comments
    });
    Navigate("/");
  };



    return (
    <div>
      <form action=''>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
          <input
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            id="name"
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor='short_name'>Short Name</label>
          <input
            value={shortName}
            onChange={(e) => setShortName(e.target.value)}
            id="name"
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor='parent_org'>Parent Organization</label>
          <input
            value={parentOrg}
            onChange={(e) => setParentOrg(e.target.value)}
            id="name"
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor='website'>Website</label>
          <input
            value={website}
            onChange={(e) => setWebsite(e.target.value)}
            id="name"
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor='comments'>Comments</label>
          <input
            value={comments}
            onChange={(e) => setComments(e.target.value)}
            id="name"
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
        {/* <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          className="btn btn-primary"
        >
          Submit
        </button> */}
      </form>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default OrganizationUpdateForm
```

```js
{
  "status": "success",
  "results": 1,
  "data": {
    "organizations": [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "International Aids Vaccine Initiative",
        "name_localized": "IAVI",
        "parent_org_id": null,
        "website": "",
        "comment": "",
        "create_date": "2019-08-26T12:42:49.457Z",
        "logo": null,
        "short_name": "IAVI"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Above is the response when I hit the API with "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/organizations/20" which is the correct response. Below is the code for AdminPortal

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default  axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/"
})
```

This is a screen capture of the network response

[image: Network Response]

The last line in the {id} has no response and I'm wondering if that might be a clue and I'm also surprise to see the port change from 3001 to 3000. I did change to response.data.organizations which seems to match with the structure in the response but that didn't make a difference. Here is what I changed:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData () {
      // const response = await AdminPortal.get(`organizations/${id}`);
      const response = await AdminPortal.get(`organizations/${id}`);
      console.log(response.dataorganizations);
      setName(response.data.organizations.name);
      setShortName(response.data.organizations.short_name);
      setParentOrg(response.data.organizations.parent_org);
      setWebsite(response.data.organizations.website);
      setComments(response.data.organizations.comments);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am getting this warning in the console: "Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component".

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the response from the backend in the developer tools network tab? What does the response look like? What does AdminPortal look like? Is it possible that you should access response.data.organizations.name instead of response.data.data.organizations.name ?